# Ajax запрос для HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#

Создаётся ли новый экземпляр `HttpContext.Current.Items` при Ajax запросе (Ajax с использованием `__doPostBack()` из JavaScript)? Т.е. если в предыдущем ajax-запросе Items что-то содержало, то будет ли Items содержать это что-то при новом ajax-запросе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) - коллекция, сохраняющаяся в пределах одного запроса (не важно: обычного, PostBack или Ajax). Между запросами элементы не сохраняются. Если нужно сохранить данные между запросами, воспользуйтесь [HttpContext.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx).